# Google Drive shared folders with per-user permissions?

Tags: google-drive, permissions

I will be using GD as a backup solution from a school server where some folders are shared but others are private.

Staff users will be granted full control to all GD folders, breaking privacy on the private folders.

I wonder if is there a way to protect personal folders, otherwise I won't be able to upload and synchronize private folders.

Comment: It would seem you're looking to use the wrong tool for the job. A shared folder shares all of the folders beneath it as well. While you can share a subfolder with _more_ people, you can't share it with _fewer_. You'll need to look for a different solution.

Comment: Probably if using GD, I will synchronise only common folders. Are you aware of a sync tool similar to drive that will retain folder/user permissions?

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations are off-topic here. Try [softwarerecs.se] instead.